# Ionic Cordova FileTransfer upload options or How to set value to be available on nodejs express middleware using req.value?

Tags: node.js, cordova, express, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic. I am trying to upload a file to server and basically what I need is to push a json object to be sent with the FileTransfer.upload and be able to recober this object on the server side using an express middleware from the request:

req.value = ${value_sent_by_ionic_client_upload};

I am current setting the object as a params entry and I can see the object in the FileUploadOptions but the object is not accessible on the server side as a value of request.

Current client side:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.filename = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

var params = {};
params.user = StorageService.getUser();
options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL,
  encodeURI("http://192.168.192.62:3000/api/meals/picture"),
  pictureUploaded,
  uploadError,
  options);
```

On server side express middleware:

```
var user = req.user;
```

but user is undefined on server side.

How to I pass the user using cordova FileTransfer.upload to make it available from a req.user call?

Answer (score 0):

this is  a bit late but maybe it can help someone looking for a code to upload 
by the way i don't think cloudinary provides any option to send users
here you're using an upload made with jquery while you're using angularjs for ionic which is not really optimal i might suggest a code like this

```
$scope.uploadimage = function()
{
  var options = new FileUploadOptions()
    options.fileKey = "image";

    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('Link-to-your-server', $scope.yourpicture, options).then(function(result) {
        console.log("File upload complete");
        console.log(result);
        $scope.uploadResults = "Upload completed successfully"            
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("File upload error");
        console.log(err);
        $scope.uploadResults = "Upload failed"                           
    }, function (progress) {
        // constant progress updates
        console.log(progress);
    });

}
```